# IE9 state/store select options will not append

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I'm encountering a troublesome javascript error in IE9 and below.  I have two select boxes.  One is a "Select Your State" box.  This select filters the options of the select to options in that state.

It works as expected in everything I've tried but IE.  As you can see in the HTML sample, the options are enclosed in optgroups.  I create an object of the options on document.ready and then remove them from the DOM.  On change of the state select box I place a subset of the options, with optgroups, into the store select.  However, IE places just the optgroups, but not the options.  I've tried a few different methods of appending the elements to the select, but IE just won't append the child options of the optgroups.

Here's simplified html and applicable javascript.  This is a Drupal site, so I'm working with jQuery 1.4.4.

```
<select id="edit-state">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
</select>
```

Assuming Arizona were selected, this should be the HTML of the second select box:

```
<select id="edit-store">
    <optgroup label="AZChandler">
        <option value="SPCHRAZ">Store Name</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="AZPhoenix">
        <option value="SPPVAAZ">Store Name</option>
        <option value="SPSCTAZ">Store Name</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="AZScottsdale">
        <option value="SPRNTAZ">Store Name</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="AZTempe">
        <option value="SPTEMAZ">Store Name</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="AZTucson">
        <option value="SPORAAZ">Store Name</option>
        <option value="SPSPEAZ">Store Name.</option>
        <option value="SPRRDAZ">Store Name</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Here's the javascript. This function is called on change of #edit-state.  The options argument is an object of all of the optgroups and options.  This functions filters and appends them.

```
function setStateOptions(options){
  var stateabbr = jQuery('#edit-state').find('option').filter(':selected').attr('value');
    jQuery('#edit-store optgroup').remove();

    jQuery(options).each(function() {
        var label = jQuery(this).attr('label');
        var abbr = label.substr(0, 2);
        if(abbr == stateabbr){
          var clone = jQuery(this).clone();
          jQuery(clone).appendTo('#edit-store');
         }
    });
    //remove postal code abbr from beginning of optgroup labels.
    jQuery('#edit-store optgroup').each(function(){
        var optlabel = jQuery(this).attr('label');
        jQuery(this).attr('label', optlabel.substr(2));
    });  
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `"However, IE places just the s, but not the s. "` please explain that

Comment: I was expecting <optgroup>s and <options>s to be plain text.  Corrected typos.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code a little bit to test grabbing optgroups from one select and placing them in another. The following seems to work fine in IE9, with jquery 1.4.4. My theory now is that the problem is not with the function, but the parameter you pass in.

```
<select id="edit-store">
    <optgroup label="AZChandler">
        <option value="SPCHRAZ">SPCHRAZ</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="AZPhoenix">
        <option value="SPPVAAZ">SPPVAAZ</option>
        <option value="SPSCTAZ">SPSCTAZ</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="AZScottsdale">
        <option value="SPRNTAZ">SPRNTAZ</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="AZTempe">
        <option value="SPTEMAZ">SPTEMAZ</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="AZTucson">
        <option value="SPORAAZ">SPORAAZ</option>
        <option value="SPSPEAZ">SPSPEAZ</option>
        <option value="SPRRDAZ">SPRRDAZ</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>​
<select id="Select2">
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#edit-store optgroup').each(
        function () {
            var label = jQuery(this).attr('label');
            var abbr = label.substr(2, 1);
            if (abbr == 'T') {
                var clone = jQuery(this).clone();
                jQuery(clone).appendTo('#Select2');
            }
        }
    );
</script>
```